# dom.ready handler for specific web page

Tags: jquery, html, client-side

Be light on me being struggling.

- I have client side JS with $(function() {...}); handler in it
- I have 4 different web pages. page1 page2 page3 page4
- Every page has its own dom elements and each element has client side jQuery/JS handler
- Now I register these callbacks/handlers in dom.ready handler
- MY PROBLEM is dom.ready handler does not distinguish b/w which page is rendered and will register all the callbacks in sequence for all pages **where I think its un-neccessary to execute code in browser to register callbacks for page2 when only page1 is rendered.**  I am not sure if this is how I should think.

Questions;

1. Is it possible for me call specific dom.ready handler when a specific page is rendered?
2. Is that a good practice?

Please help and be light on me.

Comment: Are you dealing with modal dialogs? If so, are you sure you aren't actually seeing the effects of loading multiple instances of the jQuery libraries?

Comment: I am not dealing with modal dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it might not be the best example, something that has worked for us in the past is if we look for a specific element on the page. The easiest thing to do is give each page a unique ID and simply look for it, for example:

```
<body id="page1">
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

    var el = document.getElementById('page1');

    if (el) {
        // Do only Page 1 stuff...
    }

});

</script>
</body>
```